# Как реализовать вывод статей блога по категориям?

Tags: php

Я хочу реализовать вывод записей в блоге по категориям при клике на список категорий в меню. Я создал две таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и набросал код, но в итоге он не пашет, var_dump показывает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При клике на любую из категорий, результат вывода функции var_dump не меняется. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема, где я накосячил? Заранее благодарю.
Исходный код:
 - Вывод категорий в меню и осуществление GET-запроса по id категории:

```
<?php foreach($category as $categ){ ?>
                <li><a href="category.php?category_id=<?php echo $categ['id']?>"><?php echo $categ['title']; ?></a><li>
                <?php } ?>
```

- function.php

```
//Выборка из таблицы "Категории"
$category = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM category");
$categ = mysqli_fetch_assoc($category);

//Выборка из таблицы "Посты"
$posts = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM posts");
$post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts);

function get_post_by_category($category_id){
global $connect;
global $post;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE id =".$post['category_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
return $post; 
}
```

category.php

```
require_once 'header.php';
$category_id = $_GET['category_id'];
$post = get_post_by_category($category_id);
```

Comment: А URL меняется при клике? Не используйте global (в get_post_by_category global $post вообще не нужен). Проверяйте что вам пришло от пользователя через GET и POST

Comment: Как минимум следует изменить sql запрос. `"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id = :catergoryId". И почитать про подготовленные запросы

Comment: Применяйте только $_GET для определения категории. Для того чтобы каждая категория имела свою ссылку.
У вас ошибка с переменной $category_id вы ее в функцию передаете но внутри функции не используете

Comment: @DaemonHK Да, URL меняется.

Comment: @AntonKucenko вот что выдаёт `Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\OpenServer\OSPanel\domains\lesson\function.php on line 25`

Comment: @heyone Вы просто скопировали код? Я же написал почитать про подготовленные запросы, и заменить потом `:categoryId` на свой параметр https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить посты определенной категории, можно использовать такую функцию

```
function get_post_by_category($connect, $category_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id=?";
    $result = $connect->execute_query($sql, [$category_id]);
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: результат функции var_dump при клике на ссылку меняется, а как теперь это дело связать с таблицей с постами, чтобы выводились посты определённой категории?

Comment: переменную `$sql` присваивать к выборке всех постов из таблицы 'posts'?

Comment: @heyone Вместо таблицы category делайте выборку из таблицы постов

Comment: это не то, я так делал, все равно не тот результат

Comment: @heyone А вы так пробовали? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id =".$category_id;    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);    $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: да, все равно не то.

Comment: @heyone все равно не то что? Не выводятся посты, возникает ошибка? Попробуйте запрос напрямую в phpmyadmin'е прописать

Comment: не выводит посты

Answer (score -1):

Я решил данную проблему. Если кому интересно как реализовать вывод статей из блога, а также вывод по категориям, то вот рабочий код:

function.php (Файл с функциями)

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

//Вывод данных из таблицы "Категории"
function get_category($connect){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$categories = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $categories;
}

//Вывод данных из таблицы "Посты"
function get_posts($connect){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $posts;
}

//GET запросы к post.php | Получение массива поста, открытие новой страницы с полной 
статьёй
function get_post_by_id($post_id){
global  $connect; //Объявление глобальной переменной, которая отвечает за подключение 
к БД
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id =".$post_id; //Выборка элементов из таблицы по 
id и присвоение GET-запроса
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); //Переменная, которая подключается к БД и 
присваивает значения переменной $sql
$separate_post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //Переменная, которая принимает записи 
в таблице posts по id в виде ассоциативного массива
return $separate_post; //Возвращение результата
}

function get_posts_by_category($connect, $category_id){
$category_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $category_id);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE category_id = "'.$category_id.'"';
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $posts;
}


?>
```

header.php (Шапка сайта)

```
require_once 'connect.php';
require_once 'function.php';
$categories = get_category($connect);

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Тестовый блог | Главная</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
target="#responsive-menu">
<span class="sr-only">Открыть навигацию</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Тестовый блог</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<?php foreach($categories as $category){ ?>
<li><a href="category.php?id=<?=$category["id"]?>"><? 
=$category["title"]?></a><li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

category.php (Страница с постами по конкретной категории)

```
<?php

require_once 'header.php';

$category_id = $_GET['id'];
$posts = get_posts_by_category($connect, $category_id);

?>



<div class="container">
<div class="alert alert-danger">      
</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="page-header">

<h1>Категория: <?=get_category_title($_GET['id'])?></h1>
</div>
<?php foreach($posts as $post){ ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="<?php echo $post['image']; ?>" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
<h4><a href="post.php?post_id=<?=$post['id']?>"><?php echo 
$post['title']; ?></a></h4>
<p>
<?php echo mb_substr($post['text'], 0, 200) . '...'; ?>
</p>
<p><a class="btn-info btn-sm" href="post.php?post_id=<? 
=$post['id']?>">Читать полностью</a></p>
<br/>
<ul class="list-inline">
<li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> Категория:   | 
</li>
<li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> <?php echo 
$post['datetime']; ?> | </li>
<li><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i> by <a 
href="#">3 comments</a> | </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<?php require_once 'sidebar.php'; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Это всё очень плохо. Иньекции, отсутсвие логики, ноль форматирования